# Trouble calling C# method in partial class from view using MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a database table called Skill used to generate my model with a field SkillIndex that is a smallint (byte) indexing into an enumerated type SkillEnum.  I want to map the enumerated type values to their String counterparts with `skillToString()`.  When I call the index link created by the view, the item generated is not parsed.  Here are the details:

PARTIAL CLASS (part of):

```
namespace RpgApp2.Models
{
  public enum SkillEnum { Appraise, Bluff, Climb, Diplomacy, Intimidate, Jump, Perception };

  [MetadataType(typeof(SkillMetaData))]
  public partial class Skill
  {
    Utility util;

    public String skillToString()
    {
        byte i = (byte) this.SkillIndex;
        switch (i)
        {
            case (byte)SkillEnum.Appraise: return "Appraise";
            case (byte)SkillEnum.Bluff: return "Bluff";
            case (byte)SkillEnum.Diplomacy: return "Diplomacy";
            case (byte)SkillEnum.Climb: return "Climb";
            case (byte)SkillEnum.Intimidate: return "Intimidate";
            case (byte)SkillEnum.Jump: return "Jump";
            case (byte)SkillEnum.Perception: return "Perception";
            case (byte)SkillEnum.Ride: return "Ride";
            case (byte)SkillEnum.Spellcraft: return "Spellcraft";
            case (byte)SkillEnum.Survival: return "Survival";

            default: return "No matching skill for " + (int)i;
        }
```

VIEW source code (Index.cshtml, partial):

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
  <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CharacterIndex)
    </td>
    <td>
         <% item.SkillToString(); %>
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ranks)
    </td>
```

OUTPUT SOURCE (ie view source of page generated in Internet Explorer:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        1
    </td>
    <td>
         <% item.SkillToString(); %>
    </td>
    <td>
        1
    </td>
    <td>
        3
    </td>
```

The `<% item.SkillToString(); %>` renders as itself and appears blank in the web page, whereas I want "Diplomacy" to appear for the value of 3.

What do I need to get the method `skillToString()` method called on the current item (i.e., a Skill)?

Comment: You need to use Razor syntax, not ASPX syntax.

Comment: `((SkillEnum)this.SkillIndex).ToString()` will remove that huge chunk of code.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Razor view engine, you can use:

```
@item.SkillToString()
```